# My Login API code throwing error and is not connecting with database

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, authentication

I built the signup API and registration API I am having trouble with the login API I have written the code the problem is that right now it is not connecting with the database and the login criteria has two fields username and Employee_password but the API is not connecting with the database so because of that I am not able to move forward.

```
app.post('/emp/login', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Internal server error' });
      }
  
      const { username, Employee_password } = req.body;
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Internal server error' });
        }
  
        if (results.length === 0) {
          return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials' });
        }
  
        const user = results[0]; 
        bcrypt.compare(Employee_password, user.Employee_password, (err, match) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Internal server error' });
          }
  
          if (!match) {
            return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials' });
          }
  
          const token = jwt.sign({ username : username }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
          res.json({ token });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you post a log of the `err` you are getting from the `getConnection` method?

Comment: I did it was showing error that i the database named user doesnt exist so i corrected that mistake but new error is that the result is not defined